# Adding iad to an app caused it to be rejected

Tags: ios, iad, ads

This is my third app I've tried to add iad to.  The other two used the same code to show advertisements, but once they were approved, they didn't show any ads even after over two weeks.  When I tried to check the iad report it said that the iad network was temporarily unavailable (about a month so far). Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later. If the problem persist please contact us.
Apple was by no means helpful in figuring out why.
When the third app went into review, it was rejected because:
We have verified that your app contains code that is accessing the Advertising Identifier, however, we did not see ads served in your app. As stated in section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, an app must serve ads in order to use the Advertising Identifier:

“You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier.”

We have seen this behavior in apps that include third-party libraries. These libraries are often analytics engines, ad engines, or other types of third-party services.

We require that you locate and remove this code prior to resubmitting, and recommend that you use the "nm" tool or the command line tools "strings" or "otool -ov" to find the following entities:

- class: ASIdentifierManager
- selector: advertisingIdentifier
- framework: AdSupport.framework

If you are unable to locate these entities, you may wish to work with an Apple Developer Technical Support engineer.

If you believe your app is serving ads, please:

- ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed previous versions of your app prior to testing
- provide us the steps to locate ads in your appPLA 3.3.12

We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:

"You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."

Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.

If your app is serving ads, please:

- Ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed all previous versions of your app prior to testing
- Provide us the steps to locate ads in your app

If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

class: ASIdentifierManager
selector: advertisingIdentifier
framework: AdSupport.framework

If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have included ad functionality.

To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For information on the “nm” tool, please see the nm man page.

If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls, and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.

I've checked and after the game loads, a test advertisement appears within a few seconds on the simulator and device.  Is there a step I'm missing or is this just a problem with Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the plist properly?

If you use **IFA**, you need to push ads.
Apple rejects apps that make frivolous use of **IFA**.

And just to stress that the error may actually not be on your side, have you attempted to provide the reviewers a screen shot?

Comment: Not sure what IFA is.  I submitted a screenshot several hours ago, but they haven't replied. If it is an issue on my side, I would like to fix and resubmit as soon as possible

Comment: IFA is the Identifier For Advertiser. It appears that the reviewers mention that under the name `Advertising Identifier`

Comment: They finally responded to my screenshot. They said that showing a screenshot of advertisements working on my app provides no evidence that advertisements work on my app